# owl-carousel2 height

Tags: html

Всем привет. Возникла проблема со слайдером. Картинка не растягивается по высоте, вернее я не очень понимаю для какого селектора нужно указывать высоту, чтобы картинка была нужной высоты.
По сути мне нужно, чтобы высота была задана определенная, а сама картинка была такого же расрешения как и до этого, но видна была бы только та часть, которая попадает в область[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
на первой картинке показано как должно быть, а на второй как у меня (то что картинки разные - ничего страшного, главное суть[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Answer (score 1):

Легче всего картинку вставить через background, а высоту задать через padding-top, чтоб картинка заливала весь блок поставить background-size: cover, ну и выровнять ее по центру с помощью background-position: center

```css
.img_block{
  background-image: url(https://1gai.ru/uploads/posts/2015-06/1433446501_bestcars2015lead.jpg);
  padding-top: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_block"></div>
```